# C++ code works in Gedit, but not in VS (it just prints the "press any key to exit . . ." message)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gedit

I've written a program in Visual Studio on Windows, and the program compiles correctly, but does not display the desired output to the console. However, if I compile and run the program in Gedit on Linux, the correct output displays and everything works. Why is this? Code is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string input;

cout << "College Admission Generator\n\n";

cout << "To begin, enter the location of the input file (e.g. C:\\yourfile.txt):\n";
cin >> input;


ifstream in(input.c_str());

if (!in)
{
    cout << "Specified file not found. Exiting... \n\n";
    return 1;
}

char school, alumni;
double GPA, mathSAT, verbalSAT;
int liberalArtsSchoolSeats = 5, musicSchoolSeats = 3, i = 0;

while (in >> school >> GPA >> mathSAT >> verbalSAT >> alumni)
{

    i++;

    cout << "Applicant #: " << i << endl;
    cout << "School = " << school;
    cout << "\tGPA = " << GPA;
    cout << "\tMath = " << mathSAT;
    cout << "\tVerbal = " << verbalSAT;
    cout << "\tAlumnus = " << alumni << endl;

    if (school == 'L')
    {
        cout << "Applying to Liberal Arts\n";

        if (liberalArtsSchoolSeats > 0)
        {

            if (alumni == 'Y')
            {

                if (GPA < 3.0)
                {
                    cout << "Rejected - High school Grade is too low\n\n";
                }

                else if (mathSAT + verbalSAT < 1000)
                {
                    cout << "Rejected - SAT is too low\n\n";
                }

                else
                {
                    cout << "Accepted to Liberal Arts!!\n\n";
                    liberalArtsSchoolSeats--;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (GPA < 3.5)
                {
                    cout << "Rejected - High school Grade is too low\n\n";
                }

                else if (mathSAT + verbalSAT < 1200)
                {
                    cout << "Rejected - SAT is too low\n\n";
                }

                else
                {
                    cout << "Accepted to Liberal Arts\n\n";
                    liberalArtsSchoolSeats--;
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Rejected - All the seats are full \n";
        }
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Applying to Music\n";

        if (musicSchoolSeats>0)
        {
            if (mathSAT + verbalSAT < 500)
            {
                cout << "Rejected - SAT is too low\n\n";
            }

            else
            {
                cout << "Accepted to Music\n\n";

                musicSchoolSeats--;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Rejected - All the seats are full\n";
        }
    }
    cout << "*******************************\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

To clarify, the program does compile in VS. It opens the file, but does not echo any information from the file, and instead just prints the "press any key to exit . . ." message.

Comment: What error message did you see? Did it compile? Maybe you just need to include `#include <string>`?

Comment: Where exactly it doesn't work, how exactly it doesn't work, it's nothing to do with your editor, maybe wrong file, maybe compiler etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `string input;` and `cin >> input;`. These statements require the `<string>` header but you did not include it (explicitly). In some implementations you can get away with free rides since `<iostream>` includes the `<string>` header. But you should not. Always include the appropriate header:

```
#include <string>
```

Without the above header your code [will compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02dda32ae8307b4a) on Linux using g++ (which is what you are using) but not on Windows using Visual C++. That being said use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to accept strings from the standard input instead of `std::cin`.